# initialize state react, to solve undefined when the page first rendered

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dictionary, initialization, state

I want to map a state, but that state (the name of the state is "task", it is the child of parent state called "timesheet", the "timesheet" state is already defined using componentWillMount) is still undefined UNTIL an action creator has been triggered (click a button) inside my page. But, i already define timesheet.task.map inside jsx, and thus the page cannot load and it shows an error "cannot read property map of undefined". 
[code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w0jeO.png)
So as you can see here, i want to map a list of 'select' options from a state which is called when an event is triggered (it is still undefined when the page renders), but the page will not load because the timesheet.task is still undefined when the page load the first time

Do you have any idea how to fix this? I was thinking to initialize the state, but i don't know how to do it.Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Very common situation. At the top of your `render()` - just add a conditional to check if that value is valid or not.. something like:

```
if (!this.state.timesheet.task) {
  return <p> waiting for my value </p> // add any generic component to here that would await your value 
}
```

Depending on your page layout, you might want to just create a small component to inject as a conditional as you await your value to be populated.

Comment: i'm sorry but that gives an infinite loading on my page when it loads, because the "button" it self is rendered when another action creator is called (it is placed inside the componentWillMount ). I was thinking to create a constructor to give a default value to the timesheet.task, but i don't know how to write that. Do you have any idea?